# Specific project PHP files returning blank pages

Tags: php, web-services, webserver

So, I have this project uploaded at *webwire.in/alpha* , but it's returning blank pages.

```
PHP Fatal error:  require(): Failed opening required './classes/Cookie.php' (include_path='.:/usr/share/php:/usr/share/pear in /var/www/html/alpha/core/init.php on line 22
```

and one on line 25.

Line 21-23 code = `spl_autoload_register(function($class) {
    require_once ('./classes/' . $class . '.php'); //line 22
});`

Line 25 = `require_once ('./functions/sanitize.php');`

Tricky thing about this error is that this works only for this `alpha` folder. It was occurring yesterday also but *somehow* got fixed. Now when I deleted the files and uploaded, the error is back. Yesterday, at least the `alpha/admin` was working, but today nothing is working in this alpha folder.

One more thing, I've uploaded the same file to a different server, and it works flawlessly. See here - crowdsourced.in/rationshop   (shared hosting)

Current server is a VPS if that matters.

I am not expert here, still tried solutions as I searched, but none worked for me till now.

Any help is highly appreciated.

Comment: The error doesn't necessarily mean the the file is missing. You may have a permissions issue.

Comment: And how to troubleshoot that ? Shall I try changing permissions of `~/alpha` ? I do not want to mess with permissions as they usually don't leave the option of undo if anything goes wrong.

Comment: No, look at the Cookie.php file. Check both permissions and owner/group. They should match the other files in that folder.

Comment: Everything seems to be normal.

http://i.imgur.com/jHBzpsy.png

Answer (score 0):

Pages included are included relative to the page that was loaded, not the script doing the include.

So, if you have a script in the folder: `/var/www/html/alpha/admin/`

And that includes the script: `/var/www/html/alpha/core/init.php`

And `init.php` includes the file `./functions/sanitize.php`

Then init.php is looking relative to the folder `/var/www/html/alpha/admin/` which is where the initial script was loaded. Not looking relative to the `init.php` script. It is looking for a file at: `/var/www/html/alpha/admin/functions/sanitize.php` which doesn't exist. I'm assuming it exists under `/var/www/html/alpha/core/functions/sanitize.php`.

The easy fix is to use `__DIR__` which is a built in php magic constant that has the value of the current script (the currently included file). Inside of `/var/www/html/alpha/core/init.php`, `__DIR__` == `/var/www/html/alpha/core/`. So you can include/require `__DIR__."/functions/sanitize.php`

Comment: This is all true of course, but the fact that it works on 1 server and not another makes me think it's either a file missing or a file that can't be accessed due to permissions.

Comment: `sanitize.php` is indeed in `/var/www/html/alpha/functions/` , not in `~/core`. I have rechecked again and again, and failed to find any file missing. Only permission issue is what coming to my mind. But then the question arises how do I troubleshoot in this scenario ?
Also, as I can see in FileZilla, all permissions seem to be OK, nothing unusual.